# Android: Vimeo video not playing inside webview

Tags: android, webview, vimeo

I have to play vimeo videos inside webview, consider the below code:

```
<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/74175376' width='100%' height='500px' frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I play this, it plays only the audio but the video is black.
I am using the below code:

```
WebSettings s = wv.getSettings();
wv.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
s.setSavePassword(true);
s.setSaveFormData(true);
s.setAllowFileAccess(true); 
s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
s.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
s.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
s.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {

} else {
    s.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
}
```

Any hints why this is happening...

Comment: u need customize webview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written customized webview for vimeo videos .

checkout my project below to play vimeo videos :
[Source Code](https://github.com/jkwiecien/html5webview/blob/master/HTML5WebView/src/org/itri/html5webview/HTML5WebView.java)

Basically you need to write html5 webview :

```
public class HTML5WebView extends WebView {

    private Context                             mContext;
    private MyWebChromeClient                   mWebChromeClient;
    private View                                mCustomView;
    private FrameLayout                         mCustomViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback  mCustomViewCallback;

    private FrameLayout                         mContentView;
    private FrameLayout                         mBrowserFrameLayout;
    private FrameLayout                         mLayout;

    static final String LOGTAG = "HTML5WebView";

    private void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;     
        Activity a = (Activity) mContext;

        mLayout = new FrameLayout(context);

        mBrowserFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(R.layout.custom_screen, null);
        mContentView = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

        mLayout.addView(mBrowserFrameLayout, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);

        // Configure the webview
        WebSettings s = getSettings();
        s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        s.setSaveFormData(true);
        s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
        setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

        setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
 
        // Enable Web Storage: localStorage, sessionStorage
        s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mContentView.addView(this);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    public FrameLayout getLayout() {
        return mLayout;
    }

    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if ((mCustomView == null) && canGoBack()){
                goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        private Bitmap      mDefaultVideoPoster;
        private View        mVideoProgressView;

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
        {
            // Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on ShowCustomView");
            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }

            mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            System.out.println("Customview hide !");
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;        

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            HTML5WebView.this.goBack();
            //Log.i(LOGTAG, "set it to webVew");
        }


        @Override
        public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {
            //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on getVideoLoadingPregressView");

            if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
                mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_loading_progress, null);
            }
            return mVideoProgressView; 
        }

         @Override
         public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
            ((Activity) mContext).setTitle(title);
         }

         @Override
         public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
             ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, newProgress*100);
         }

         @Override
         public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
             callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
         }
    }


    static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS =
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

Comment: Thanks adcorn... Yes I saw this before and didn't used this, because was not able to understand it completely, can you explain what really is the issue with vimeo that this class solves ?

Comment: above code is ChromeClient which comes from android webkit, before in stackoverflow i have posted same question and the HTML5 code wriiten above was a solution for my issue...since chome webview supports some fetures like js and all this WebChromeClient worked...and android provides this in webkit so y to take much efforts

Comment: can u provide me video link u r using?

Comment: its playing at my end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58651/discussion-between-viv-and-adcom).

Comment: May be If I use your code it plays, but still I can't get what actually this code does that is necessary to play video...

Comment: Finally I have integrated, your code is inspiration thanks. Now there is another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25140283/android-vimeo-video-inside-webview-crashing-second-time-i-play-it

Comment: while playing vimeo video if we press home button, it keeps on playing the video. I tried web view.onPause() but it's not working. Any solution ?

Comment: When I try to check source code from your link get below error                                   
  {
error: {
code: "generalException",
message: "General Exception While Processing"
}
}