# Android Vimeo video inside webview crashing second time I play it

Tags: android, webview, vimeo

I am playing vimeo videos inside webview, for source code you can have a look at:
[Android: Vimeo video not playing inside webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130801/android-vimeo-video-not-playing-inside-webview)

Now there is another issue, when I play video next time it crashes with following stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.reprepareData(HTML5VideoView.java:231)
    at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy$VideoPlayer.play(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:219)
    at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy.handleMessage(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:372)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I have a fragment having webview, when I click on video, I attach a view in fragment frame layout, then when I press back video and fragment gets removed. Now when I again open fragment, and then click on video, this occurs.

Comment: can u point me HTML5VideoView.java:231?

Comment: @adcom : This is the code snippet.. http://pastebin.com/F1usMcve

Comment: is it possible to pass me small demo or so ? so that i can debug at my end?

Comment: @DIVA : Sorry for late reply here: https://app.box.com/s/xxwwrw16d5sanvjofh1i

Comment: This is working properly on kitkat update on Moto g, but not in previous versions of Android. Try running this sample code on different versions of android.

Comment: ok let me test will get u back

Comment: @viv, Did you manage to solve this issue? I also encountered this on certain device.

Comment: @jzarsuelo : It has been quite a time, I don't remember exactly.