# How can I play video from android app with a url of video obtain from youtube api data

Tags: android, video, youtube, android-youtube-api

I wonder to know how can I play youtube video which url I obtained from YoutubeAPI data v3:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpVUIwrNLoo&feature=youtube_gdata_player
```

I have the following code that perform this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    String uri = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    //Uri url = Uri.parse(uri);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoPath(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.start();
}
```

and the layout xml is like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Please I wonder for any help as soon as possible.

Comment: try those options : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574195/android-youtube-app-play-video-intent

Comment: look at this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130801/android-vimeo-video-not-playing-inside-webview/25130834?noredirect=1#comment39116183_25130834